# input fields shows errors when left empty

Tags: php, forms, input

I have a survey form which contains lots of input fields. When I try to fill all the input fields it saves to the database. But when I only fill a few of the input fields and leave other fields blank it does not save and it shows error like these.

```
Notice: Undefined index: scale_fun in C:\xampp\htdocs\survey1\includes\save2.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: job_performance in C:\xampp\htdocs\survey1\includes\save2.php on line 24
```

what should I do to remove these errors?

Comment: Check if variables are set before you use them

Answer (score 0):

try to make validation in the front (before submitting the form)  or backend ( after submitting the form ) OR You can set columns to accept Null from the database.

[image]

check this too : ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Comment: Never rely on front-end validation alone (can be tampered with), always use backend validation